# How to convert the multiple text file into csv right format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, text

I have many text files in a very specific format that need to be read into a csv. I can not seem to figure out how to get all the data in the format that I want in my csv. I can get the file name and the header for the sheet, but none of the data is active in the sheet. The text file is as follows:

```
ID                              0x20f7
City                            Metropolitian
Time_taken (min)                    42.000000
```

My texts files like this:

```
0.txt,
1.txt,
3.txt,
5.txt,
6.txt,
9.txt,
10.txt
```

I tried like this:

```
csvout = pd.DataFrame()

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dataset/train/", "*.txt"))

for filename in file_list:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='   ', index_col=0, header=None).T
    csvout = csvout.append(data)

csvout.to_csv("train.csv")
```

I need a output like this:

```
ID      City           Time_taken (min)
0x20f7  Metropolitian  42.00000
```

0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to get the expected format :

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dataset/train/", "*.txt"))

list_df=[]
for filename in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='   ', header=None)
    df = df.pivot_table(columns=0, values=1, aggfunc='first')
    list_df.append(df)
    out = pd.concat(list_df)

out = out[['ID', 'City', 'Time_taken (min)']] # to re-order the columns
out.to_csv("train.csv", index=False)
```

##### Output (Excel) :

Example with four .txt files that have one city each :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the input text files contain a list of key values, like a dictionary? And each file should result in one record in the output dataframe, right? You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

# create empty dataframe
csvout = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["ID", "City", "Time_taken (min)"])

# get list of files
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dataset/train/", "*.txt"))

for filename in file_list:
    # next file/record
    mydict = {}
    with open(filename) as datafile:
        # read each line and split on "  " space
        for line in datafile:
            # Note: partition result in 3 string parts, "key", "   ", "value"
            # array slice third parameter [::2] means steps=+2
            # so only take 1st and 3rd item
            name, var = line.partition("   ")[::2]
            mydict[name.strip()] = var.strip()
        # put dictionary in dataframe
        csvout = csvout.append(mydict, ignore_index=True)

# write to csv
csvout.to_csv("train.csv", sep=";", index=False)
```

**EDIT**: The line `with open(filename) etc.` opens a file and implicitly closes it in garbage collection or when program ends. Not sure if it matters, but for so many >10.000 files in a loop it's maybe better to explicitly close the file(?). So change some lines like this:

```
    # new record
    mydict = {}
    datafile = open(filename, "r")
    # read each line and split on "  " space
    for line in datafile:

        # etc..

    # put dictionary in dataframe
    csvout = csvout.append(mydict, ignore_index=True)
    # explicitly close file
    datafile.close()
```

Comment: @ BDR ,I have 10900 files, when tried your code my jupyter memory is run off.

Comment: @jacky789 Maybe it's better to explicitly close the files, although I'm not sure if that matter for memory-use, see my edited answer. Also, you could try running the Python script in the IDLE command line tool instead of Jupyter Notebook, maybe that uses less memory(?)